# Make Invoke-WebRequest loop through each URL it finds

Tags: powershell, webrequest

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm trying to make the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet loop through each url the webscrape finds. All I have so far is this :

```
$site = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri www.example.com/examples
$site.Links | Out-GridView
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Loop through them and do ... what?

Comment: Store them in a variable and loop through the new results until there are no new results.

Comment: Are they not already in a variable with a links property?

Comment: Sorry could you explain? I'm still very new to this, I only got the code off a website.

Comment: You're new to "explaining what you want"? `$site.Links` is a variable with all the links in it. What are "*new results*"? When are there "*no more new results*"?

Comment: This is crazy, you want a recursive reference to the `Links` property? Like you could ever hit a web page with no hyperlinks what-so-ever? It really sounds like you want something that gets all links from a page, goes to those pages, gets all their links, goes to those pages, and gets all their links, and goes on forever like that. Are you trying to download the entire internet?

Comment: It just sounds like he is trying to scrape links from a website and store them in a variable.  Knowing more about the site in question would be helpful, or at least the HTML being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Add your links to a comma separated list.

Split the list and loop each item.

Request each item.

As below:

```
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$urlCollection = "link1,link2,link3"
$separator = ","
$urlList = $urlCollection.Split($separator, $option)

foreach ($url in $urlList) {

    Invoke-WebRequest $url

    # Give feedback on how far we are
    Write-Host ("Initiated request for {0}" -f $url)
}
```